# Extract only the handwriting text from a pdf using OCR

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision, handwriting-recognition

I am working OCR handwriting to text conversion using [Google cloud vision api](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf).

Input is a pdf with 1-5 pages, but the catch is the each page of pdf can have default header and footer printed on it and in between that, an answer would be written by the student.

I am doing this in nodejs but open to suggestions if I can do this with accuracy.

Now the issue is, google OCR is converting everything into the plain text without telling which one was printed text vs handwriting.

Any which way I can achieve that?

Comment: One condition - the headers and footers are unknown, can be different for each pdf uploaded. They can also be of different sizes, so can't remove from the pdf automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A `feature request` has been filed regarding the **Google Cloud Vision API's** `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` whether the text is handwritten or typed/printed. This feature has been anticipated by many users. By staying updated, you can follow the link of this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154156890) or always take a look at [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes).

There are other ways to achieve it by using other 3rd party tools such as ABBYY, Nanonets OCR API, Kofax, etc.